# Selecting rows from same name table from multiple databases in single result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, table

*For some reason*, I have a table **Table_1** in **n** databases (same name and schema structure) *instead of one single databases*. The columns are like this:

> **| Column_1 | Column_2 |**

I can select data from those **n** databases by running this query on each of them:

```
use Database_n
select * from Table_1
```

**Problem:** This will require me to run this query **n times**. Which will return **n** result sets as shown in the below image:

[image: n number of result sets]

**Question**: Is there a way to get the data from all those databases in one single result set like this:

[image: one single result set]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure :

```
    select * from database_n.dbo.Table_1
    UNION ALL
    select * from database_n+1.dbo.Table_1
    UNION ALL
    select * from database_n+2.dbo.Table_1
    -- etc.
```